# Ngen error because "Mscorlib.dll does not have a native image" (x64 only, .NET 4.0 only)

Tags: c#, .net, native, ngen

I'm trying to generate a native image of my .NET 4.0 application using [Ngen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_Image_Generator) using a 64-bit Windows 7. When **Platform** is set to x64 (or *Any CPU*) - Ngen fails, complaining that  '**NGen cannot proceed because Mscorlib.dll does not have a native image**.'

When compiling as x86 and using the appropriate Ngen - it works fine. Also, when changing the .NET version to 2.0 - it works. (When trying to Ngen the x64 application with the x86 Ngen, it tells me I should use the 64-bit version.)

**More information**:

This is (part of) what I see in CMD: The ellipses (= ...) are present in the original.

> 1>    **Compiling** assembly **mscorlib**, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 (CLR v4.0.30319) ...
>
> 1>**mscorlib**, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

.

> 2>    Compiling assembly Accessibility, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, Public KeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a (CLR v4.0.30319) ...

.

> 2>Ngen failed to generate native code for image Accessibility,
>   Version=4.0.0.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
>   because of the following error: **NGen cannot proceed because
>   Mscorlib.dll does not have a native image** (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131F06)

Searching inside `C:\Windows\assembly` I found 3 **mscorlib.dll**'s. One in `GAC_32`, one in `GAC_64` (both in subfolders beginning with 2.0.0.0) and one in a subfolder `temp`.

When searching inside `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET` I found six of them: two under `assembly` (in `GAC`'s `32` and `64`) both in folders that begin with 'v4.0...', and four in `Framework`'s: 2 in **Framework**, and two in **Framework64** (in each - one in 'v2.0...' and one in 'v4.0...').

Does this mean that only .NET 2.0 mscorlib's are really run as native images (when needed)? And why doesn't Ngen succeed in saving native images of .NET 4.0?

**Bottom line**: How do I create a native image of a .NET 4.0 application that targets x64?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is unhealthy.  The ngen-ed image of mscorlib.dll should have been created when .NET was installed on your machine.  It is located in c:\windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\mscorlib\ab0a8fc3d086a3aaf942f366a12a9185\mscorlib.ni.dll.  I'm not sure how well the hashed part of the directory name repeats from one machine to another.

You cannot see this file with Windows Explorer, you must use the command prompt.  Go check to see if it there, something went seriously wrong when .NET was installed if it is missing.  The ".NET Runtime Optimization Service" is the one that gets that job done, make sure you didn't disable it.

A standard mistake is running ngen.exe from a command prompt that isn't elevated.

Comment: Thanks. There are actually two folders with hash names in `c:\windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64` (neither with the hash you provided), both containing an `mscorlib.ni.dll`. (I was looking for mscorlib.dll.) I have not (knowingly) disabled the runtime optimization service. And I'm using an elevated command prompt (I actually made that mistake at first, but Ngen simply told me I needed an elevated prompt). Should I try re-installing .net 4.0?

Comment: Thank you very much yet again. Your assertion that a native image of mscorlib.dll should have been created on .net's installation convinced me to try repairing .net, and since that didn't help - I uninstalled and reinstalled .net 4.0 - which solved the problem.

Comment: I'm seeing this error on a brand new snapshotted installation of Windows 8 Pro x64.  I have an installer that ngens a VSTO AddIn and my customer experienced an installation failure in his own environment.  I built up an environment  to repro and sure it enough it fails.